# playing a youtube video on a click within iframe in a single webpage

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, anchor

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxO8LanzoiU"
   target="vid1">Geriatrics Informatiion</a> 

<iframe height="315" name="vid1" width="560"></iframe>
```

When I click the anchor link, the youtube video should play in the iframe. What should be the src attribute of iframe?

Answer (score 2):

To automatically start playing, append `autoplay=1` to the URL. For example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxO8LanzoiU&autoplay=1

The previous link loads a video including comments, etc. To only show the player use the `/embed` URL:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/NxO8LanzoiU?autoplay=1

Comment: i want to play the youtube video inside iframe which is present in same webpage as the anchor link. The above method is playing video in separate window.

Comment: @AbhilashMuthuraj Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/3CevH/, Chrome 18, Firefox 13. Which browser (include version!) is failing you?